# R Keeping column name after removing all but one column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes and I want remove all columns that colsums are 4 and under. So I only want to keep columns that have colsums of 5 or greater. My testsample is down below.

I use this code for removing the columns.

```
NEWTEST = NULL
for (a in 1:length(TEST)) {
  NEWTEST = colSums(TEST[[a]])
  index = which(NEWTEST > 4)
  TEST[[a]] = TEST[[a]][,index]}

#Change all in dataframes again
for (a in 1:length(TEST)) {
  TEST[[a]] = as.data.frame(TEST[[a]])}
```

The problem is now, that when its only 1 column left like in df2 and df3, the column name disappears. But for me that column name is very important and I need to keep it (here I just chose Vn, but in reality its a descriptive column name and different in each dataframe.

Any idea, how I can simply keep that name?

```
TEST = structure(list(df1 = structure(list(V1 = c(15L, 18L, 18L, 12L, 
                                           14L, 16L, 10L, 14L, 29L, 16L, 20L, 20L, 13L, 3L, 14L), V2 = c(0L, 
                                                                                                         1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L), V3 = c(0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                         0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V4 = c(0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V5 = c(0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V6 = c(0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("V1", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6"), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame"), 
               df2 = structure(list(V1 = c(4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                           4L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 3L), V2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                                               1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V3 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                           0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V4 = c(0L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                               0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V5 = c(0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
                                    V6 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                           0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", 
                                                                    "V6"), row.names = c(1L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 20L, 23L, 24L, 27L, 
                                                                                         28L, 29L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 37L, 38L), class = "data.frame"), 
               df3 = structure(list(V1 = c(7L, 10L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 
                                           6L, 6L, 7L, 10L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 4L), V2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                                                    0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V3 = c(0L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                        0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V4 = c(0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
                                    V5 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                           0L, 0L, 0L), V6 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                               0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", 
                                                                                                    "V4", "V5", "V6"), row.names = c(1L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
                                                                                                                                     23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 38L, 39L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("df1", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "df2", "df3"))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the `list`, create the condition with `colSums` and use that as column index.  Note that by default, if we use a index or column name without a comma, it is taken as column index/column name in `data.frame`

```
lapply(TEST, function(x) x[colSums(x) >= 5])
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(TEST, ~ .x %>%
              select(where(~ sum(.) >= 5)))
```

---

The reason for the behavior experienced with OP is based on the `drop = TRUE` in `data.frame` when there is a single row/column i.e. it drops its dimensions to return vector.  In this case, we could just subset with column index without a `,` or if we use `,`, then make sure to specify `drop = FALSE`

```
lapply(TEST, function(x) x[, colSums(x) >= 5, drop = FALSE])
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to keep the names!